# install ocsigen-bundle-2.2.2 error

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

```
$./configure --prefix ${HOME}/ocsigen OCSIGEN_USER=${USER} OCSIGEN_GROUP=${USER} --with-missing-libs
...
checking for sqlite3_open in -lsqlite3... no
configure: error: SQLite is required.  See the --with-sqlite3 configure option.

$uname -r
 [FreeBSD[ 9.0-RELEASE-p3

$whereis sqlite3
sqlite3: /usr/local/bin/sqlite3

$ls -l /usr/local/lib/libsqlite*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  602092 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     943 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la*
lrwx-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  602092 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     943 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      15 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so@ -> libsqlite3.so.8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  617995 12  3  2011 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.8*
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What is the output when you add --with-sqlite3 ?

Comment: You should submit a bug report on https://ocsigen.org/trac/ or contact authors on the [mailing list](https://sympa.mancoosi.univ-paris-diderot.fr/wws/info/ocsigen)

Comment: i have posted it to mailing list, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like

> ./configure --with-sqlite3=/usr/local/lib

or maybe just `/usr/local` to tell the ./configure script that sqlite3 is not in the standard directory (`/usr/lib`).

Comment: It reports "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl" in config.log after adding "--with-sqlite3=/usr/local".  The error message is still "configure: error: SQLite is required.  See the --with-sqlite3 configure option" .